# Canvas create an image mask that is transparent

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, masking

I have a canvas where the user can draw with a brush tool I created (on mousedown or touch).
I would like the drawing area to be restricted by a shape on the canvas, for example, the shape of a Chinese character.

The shape is not a simple shape, so using CanvasRenderingContext2D.clip() is not really an option?

My next solution is to draw the masking image as a PNG with drawImage onto the canvas, then change the CanvasRenderingContext2D.globalCompositeOperation to 'source-atop', so that the brush is drawn within the masking image only.

Here is the requirement which I am stuck at - In the final output of the canvas, I do not want to see the masking image.

I could accept setting the masking image to a very very low alpha such that is is virtually invisible.

Therefore, I tried to set the global alpha before placing the image, then restoring it when the brush starts to draw.

However, the overlap drawn also has the same alpha as the masking image, but I would like it to be at full.

Is there another way to achieve this I am not aware of?

Comment: eirikl, As you can see from our discussion below, we need some more specifics about your needs...please give us more clarity! :-)

Answer (score 3):

@markE's solution is fine for a small set of predefined characters, that you could work on before.

Unfortunately, while texts are vector drawing operations, the only two methods in canvas Context2d are [`fillText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillText) and [`strokeText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/strokeText), which doesn't allow us to include texts in a Path2D object, needed by the [`clip()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clip) method.

So if you can't do this pre-processing, I think that [globalCompositeOperation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation) is a good alternative for `clip()`.
This will involve the use of 2 canvases, one for the user's drawings, and the other one for the clipping/rendering. <sub>(Here I even use a third one for the clipping-mask, but it could also just be an `<img>` tag with a raster png with transparency).</sub>

`source-in` mode of the `globalCompositeOperation` will only draw the newly drawn pixels where there were already pixels drawn. So the first shape (the clipping mask) won't be visible.

```js
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// create a buffer canvas for the paintings
var paint = canvas.cloneNode(true);
var paint_ctx = paint.getContext('2d');

// create another buffer canvas for the clipping-mask
// (it could also be a raster png in an <img> tag
var clip_mask = canvas.cloneNode(true);
var clip_ctx = clip_mask.getContext('2d');

var clip = function(){
  // clear the visible canvas
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
  // draw the clipping mask
  ctx.drawImage(clip_mask, 0,0);
  // change the gCO
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";
  // draw the user paintings
  ctx.drawImage(paint, 0,0);
  // always reset the default gCO
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";

  // show the stroke of the clipping area
  if(stroke.checked){
    strokeMask();
    }
  };

//
// The user painting methods
//

var doPaint = function(x, y){
  paint_ctx.beginPath();
  paint_ctx.arc(x-3.5, y-3.5, 7, Math.PI, -Math.PI);
  paint_ctx.fill();
  clip();
  };


canvas.onmousemove = function(evt){
  var rect = this.getBoundingClientRect();
  var x = evt.clientX-rect.left;
  var y = evt.clientY-rect.top;
  doPaint(x,y);
  };

//
// the clipping mask methods
//

// init the clipping-mask
var initClip = function(){
  clip_ctx.font = "150px sans-serif";
  clip_ctx.textBaseline = "top";
  clip_ctx.textAlign = "center";
  updateClip();
  };

// update the clipping-mask
var updateClip = function(){
  var val = char.value;
  clip_ctx.clearRect(0, 0, clip_mask.width, clip_mask.height);
  var x = (clip_mask.width/2);
  clip_ctx.fillText(val, x, 10);
  paint_ctx.clearRect(0, 0, paint.width, paint.height);
  clip();
  };

// listen to the text input
char.oninput = char.onchange = function(){
  var val = this.value;
  // restrict to 1 character
  if(val.length>1){
    this.value = val[val.length-1];
    }
  updateClip();
  };

// show the stroke of the mask
var strokeMask = function(){
  ctx.font = "150px sans-serif";
  ctx.textBaseline = "top";
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(255,255,255,.3)";
  ctx.strokeText(char.value, canvas.width/2, 10);
  }
stroke.onchange = clip;

// lets go!
initClip();
```

```css
body{background-color: skyblue;}
canvas{border:1px solid;}
input{max-width:1em;}
span{font-size:.7em;}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="char" value="试"/>
<span>show the clipping-stroke</span><input type="checkbox" id="stroke" name="s"/><br>
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="150"></canvas>
```

Comment: Compositing works also. Wouldn't it be more direct to [use 'source-atop' compositing](https://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/a0fr29wt/)?

Comment: @markE, but then https://jsfiddle.net/a0fr29wt/1/ which is the title and the issue of the question

Comment: Then make both the CSS background and the mask yellow

Comment: hehe but then it's not "transparent" ;-) What if OP wants to export the result as png, or to overlay it on a video, are you gonna set the css background-image at each new frame?

Comment: It would be nice if the OP would clarify. But it might be their use-case allows transparent==notVisible==whiteOnWhite. Re:exporting, eliminate surviving white pixels if desired (see the first paragraph of my answer).

Comment: but what about non solid background ? I think that `source-in` is a better alternative, and anyway, both our answers have their own merits so let's wait for future readers make their own choice :-) (if you want I can remove the part I do talk about your solution, but I thought it would enlighten the fact that the pre-processing you do recommend would also enable the use of other Path methods (such as `isPointInPath()`), which is impossible with gCO

Comment: @Kaiido is correct on my use case - the resulting image needs to be a PNG.  Also the Chinese character is just an example - it's not text but a specially crafted crafted Chinese calligraphy which is a PNG.

Answer (score 1):

**How to create an "invisible" mask** If you want to avoid your masks from showing you can set your css background to white and fill your masks with white. That way the masks will be "invisible". If you need transparency, then when all drawing is done you can use `context.getImageData` to make all surviving white pixels transparent.

**But...** Compositing affects only existing vs new drawings, so the problem is if your app incrementally adds pixels, you will have to do quite a bit of saving + redrawing to use compositing to restrict pixels. That's because previously new pixels from the last draw will become existing pixels during the current compositing cycle.

**So...** Take another look at `context.clip` which restricts new drawings (brush strokes) into a defined clipping path. It's not that difficult to reduce even complex shapes to canvas paths. If you have a large volume of characters to make paths from, then consider Adobe Illustrator plus Mike Swanson's plugin that exports svg paths as canvas paths.

Comment: Why not two canvases, one with the drawings, and the other one where we'll draw the mask, then do the clipping of the drawings with gCO ? I'm away from a real keyboard for the weekend so can't test, but that should work no?

Comment: @Kaiido. Multiple ways to do this, but `context.clip` was created for this purpose so it seems most prudent to use it.

Comment: @Kaiido I forgot to mention... i want the drawing to be contained as the user draws... not masked upon completion

Comment: @markE. Unfortunately the only methods to draw text natively on canvas are fillText and strokeText, which means they won't be part of the Path2D needed by clip. IMO gCO seems a better alternative than outputting any character as a path drawing from 3rd party. Anyway, I may add an answer tomorrow if I've got time.

Comment: @Kaiido. You misunderstand. :-) Place a raster image of a Chinese character into Adobe Illustrator and have Illustrator vectorize it (Illustrator does a reasonable job at vectorization). Then use Mike Swanson's Illustrator plugin to export the vector as an html5 path command. Then you can `context.clip` the character path. Here, I'll do [an example](https://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/esk35w5r/).

Comment: @eirikrl I'm not sure I got it. Do you want to keep like the coordinates of the drawing, except when it goes off the clip area? Then even markE's solution here won't work. The solution I did talk about would be done each frame just like a "rasterized clip()", and user won't notice nothing.

Comment: @markE I got it, but if you want to do it for any 10000 Chinese characters, that starts to be a lot of work ;-) (I don't know the number of Chinese characters so it's just for the idea)