# How can I clip the area of free drawing on canvas by some image or svg?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I am using fabricjs library to activate free drawing mode. My **purpose is to bound the free drawing area to some non-primitive shape** (human shape).

I have tested the 2 implementations:

1) Convert clipping area to SVG and then use SVG with `canvas.clipTo`
But I found the problems: zooming canvas is impossible from that moment

2) Use Image with transparent background color as background image of the canvas.
The case is not working at all.

Maybe you know the way how can I set the color of Brush that will be transparent when the brush path intersects with the transparent element?
Or other solutions (no fabricjs) that will help me to get a goal.

Comment: [This recent Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35098066/canvas-create-an-image-mask-that-is-transparent/35098224#35098224) describes several methods to restrict drawing inside an arbitrary shape on native html5 canvas.